# after the implementation of the ADMX file for Office 365 - nothing appeared in the GPMC

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

We have Windows 2016DC. We want to Using GPO to update Office Click to Run Channels
. So I downloaded the Administrative Template files (ADMX/ADML) and Office Customization Tool for Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise, Office 2019, and Office 2016 and copied them to the central location \DC\sysvol\MyDomain\Policies\PolicyDefinitions

I am going to Computer Configuration > Policy > Administrative Templates, but I can't find  Microsoft Office 2016 (Computer),

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the Administrative Templates node specify it is using the central store for policy definitions, or the local computer?

Comment: we use the central store for policy definitions

Comment: did you also copy the requisite language files to the appropriate region/language subdirectory?  Did you wait an apporpriate period of time for DFS to replicate these files to all domain controllers (or at least the one you were targeting with your GPMC)?

Comment: yes, I copied both ADMX & ADML to central store each in its own file

Comment: solved, on my computer I have RSAT French version installed, but Server DC in English language, so I reinstalled RSAT English version and everything works fine. thank you to all participants